# How to shard a database like that of SO?

Tags: sharding

I know a bit about sharding but I cannot wrap my head around that fact that say eventually SO cannot scale vertically then how would they shard their SQL DB? Even if we assume SO will not reach that day consider this a theoretical problem.

We have questions by timestamp, by vote, by answers, by users and so on. How this kind of database be sharded, if possible at all?

Comment: It is a programming question I feel not something related specifically to stackexchange. Any database like SO. SO database is named just as an example. Also, those who downvote can you please explain your reason?

Comment: I did not even know that there is a dba.stackexchange,com. I am sorry for my ignorance. There are just so many sub-domains. :(

Comment: @user902384 I agree that they are many but they are in most cases useful to their purpose and worth checking ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sharding, or database partitioning, is usually done to allow parallel processing of chunks of data. Groups of records residing in different shards (partitions) can be processed independently of one another, thus effectively multiplying the database server capacity.

The biggest problem to solve when deciding the partitioning scheme is to ensure that data that are usually processed together (e.g. sets of frequently joined records) reside in the same partition. As a result the columns used to join tables (or their subsets) are often used as the partitioning key. If this principle is not followed partitioning usually turns into a big performance issue, because parallel processing of partitions becomes dependent on retrieving related sets of records from other partitions.

Subsequently, for effective partitioning the database needs to be designed from the beginning with this possibility in mind. You can't usually just "slap" partitioning on an existing database, unless the data model and queries are very simple.

Comment: Agreed. Let us say we have to do a QA database from scratch. I find it hard to shard. How would you approach the problem.